# write and read NSData from external hardrive

Tags: xcode, external, nsdata, nsfilemanager, read-data

I am searching for a way to write and read data from xcode program to an external hard drive.

If I navigate to my external hardrive via finder and go to video right click hold options and copy file path i get this.
/Volumes/GoPro Videos/videoFolder/0d33c2f2-a8d3-48c7-af41-2a47c60143a2.MP4

```
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:@"/Volumes/GoPro Videos/videoFolder/0d33c2f2-a8d3-48c7-af41-2a47c60143a2.MP4"];
NSLog(@"%lu",data.length);
```

data length is always zero. I have tried varying the path a bit chaning GoPro%20Videos or /// in front of volumes.

Comment: Is the app sandboxed? If yes you don't have permission. It's highly recommended to use the URL related API of FileManager which provides an `error` parameter.

Comment: You were right it was sandboxed.  Turning sandboxing off in capabilities and swapping to [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: options: error:] showed that I did not have permission.